# Possible to add a Wall Post text field to a Facebook Page landing page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to add a Facebook Wall post text box to a Facebook landing page that will - and here is the real catch - allow a visitor to leave a comment and fan a page **at the same time**? Basically, in a very transparent way so that the visitor knows what they are doing, we would like to build a landing page that will allow a visitor that is already familiar with our brand, to - with one click - produce a Wall post AND fan our Facebook Page at the same time. So basically, we'll say, "Please become a fan of our page, and while you're at it, why don't you say something?" and then:

1. The user will fill out the text box on the landing page
2. The user will click the "Like" button on the landing page
3. Then - more or less simultaneously - the user will become a fan of our Page and the text in the box that they wrote will turn into a post on our Wall.

So, first, is that possible, and second, if so, does anyone have an example of the code that would make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a feed dialogue to post on user's wall:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Additionally posting on user's wall automatically is a facebook policy violation. You should tell the user explicitly that you are posting on the wall and there should be a button clearly indicating that, and another to cancel the action. Facebook auto-bots are going berserk these days, and banning applications like anything. So it's better that you are careful. The policy documents can be found here:
http://developers.facebook.com/policy/
http://developers.facebook.com/policy/